# Python-returns object memory address when content of object is desired

Tags: python, object, memory, dictionary

**Specs:** Python 3.3.2

**What I was trying to do:**

> ```
> Create a simple name and employee number dictionary
> application. Have the user enter a list of names and employee numbers. Your
> interface should allow a sorted output (sorted by name) that displays employee
> names followed by their employee numbers.
> ```

**What I came up with:**

```
# enter a list of names of employees
# enter a list of employee numbers
# zip them together

def hrcat():
    name = input('Please enter names of employees: ')
    number = input('Please enter employee numbers: ')

    output = zip(name,number)
    print(output)
```

**Question:**

When given two lists of names and numbers, it returns the memory address of an object; something looks like this:

```
>>> hrcat()
Please enter names of employees: a,b,c
Please enter employee numbers: 1,2,3
<zip object at 0x7fea10ce4b90>
```

I wonder why it returns the memory address instead of the actual content of that object? I googled online but wasn't able to find answers addressing this question. Thank you for your insights!

Comment: Of course you googled online. Never saw anyone googling offline successfully... (SCNR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.x [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an iterator (which looks like `<zip object at 0x7fea10ce4b90>`). You can apply `list` to view the contents,

```
list(zip(name,number))
```

Although, if you are just making a dictionary, can forget about the list and use the iterator directly to populate it,

```
dict(zip(name,number))
```

Comment: Thanks! Though it returns `{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', ',': ','}` when the input in my question above is given. Any thoughts on the comma entry?

Comment: @hakuna121 Just `split(',')` and optionally apply `int`.

Comment: @hakuna121 Your `zip()` call zips the strings `a,b,c` and `1,2,3`, so that you match `'a'` and `'1'`, `','` and `','`, `'b'` and `'2'`, `','` and `','` again, and `'c'` and `'3'`. The duplicated `(',', ',')` tuple will be eaten up by the dict. This breaks as soon as you have numbers with more digits. So first, you should `split(',')` up the strings, making them lists, and only then `zip()` them.